# GCP Data Fusion - Can't find Replication section in the menu

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-data-fusion

I'm trying to follow [this article](https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/tutorials/replicating-data/mysql-to-bigquery) to replicate an on-prem MySQL database to BigQuery. I've setup everything needed up to the "navigate to the **Replication** page", but I can't find the replication page in the Cloud Data Fusion UI. Is this something I need to enable?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out you need to enable the Replication "accelerator" when you create your data fusion instance.
[image]

Comment: more than one year later and the documentation is still not updated